# How can I stop infinite jumping?

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

I've got my jump down but I can't find a way to stop infinite jumping.

Here is my code:

```
public class Jump: MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8f;
    private float movement = 0f;
    private Rigidbody2D rigidBody;

    private bool isGrounded;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float checkRadius;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;



    void Start()
    {
        rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        
        movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        if (movement > 0f)
        {
            rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(movement * speed, rigidBody.velocity.y);
        }
        else if (movement < 0f)
        {
            rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(movement * speed, rigidBody.velocity.y);
        }
        else
        {
            rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(0, rigidBody.velocity.y);
        }
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(rigidBody.velocity.x, jumpSpeed);
        }

        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, checkRadius, whatIsGround  );
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't checking if you are grounded before jumping, try something like this

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, checkRadius, whatIsGround);
    movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    if (movement > 0f)
    {
        rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(movement * speed, rigidBody.velocity.y);
    }
    else if (movement < 0f)
    {
        rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(movement * speed, rigidBody.velocity.y);
    }
    else
    {
        rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(0, rigidBody.velocity.y);
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded == true)
    {
        rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(rigidBody.velocity.x, jumpSpeed);
    }
}
```